# Blender 4.0 Graphics card error

Tags: error

[image][image]

Blender 4.0 crashes on open and throw this error.
I updated my drivers and the error continues.

Comment: Since you haven't told us what graphics card you are using,... Check that your graphics card is supported [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and if it is you should report bugs [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports). See also [this](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports) from the Blender manual.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using rtx3060. Works fine on Blender 3.6.5

Comment: Which driver version have you installed and from which source?

Comment: NVIDIA Studio Driver Version 546.01 . From GeForce Experience. I try with GameReady Drivers as well.

Comment: Don't know whether the graphics cards section in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0) for 4.0 apply here?

Comment: Updated with my drivers versions.

Comment: Blender is working. I installed it without copying the settings and it worked. It must be something with the Add-ons.

Comment: Hello, @YuriCoppe  .. Glad you've made some progress. If you do figure out which setting/add-on it was,that created your problem, a brief self-answer might be helpful to others. If you would rather just close out the question, delete it, or ask here, and we can do that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting user preference in the `%localappdata%` directory.

This happened probably because you imported an earlier version's preference, which has a different color profile preference than 4.0's. Building the preference from the ground up will solve this.